# Postgres Docker startup script not working

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have this docker file:

```
FROM postgres:11.1-alpine
ENV POSTGRES_USER postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD secret
ADD 00-create_user_and_db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
ADD 01-create_work_user_and_db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
ADD 02-test.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

and for example the 00- file is:

```
CREATE USER admin WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'secret';

CREATE DATABASE account;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE account TO admin;

CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
```

after docker-compose build and docker-compose up I can see the logs:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/00-create_user_and_db.sql
personal-db   | CREATE ROLE
personal-db   | CREATE DATABASE
personal-db   | GRANT
personal-db   | CREATE EXTENSION
```

Now, the only problem is the UUID-OSSP extension is not "created". Everything else is fine.

**I can run that in the db console and it will work.**

Not sure what's the problem here